# Search field in java webpage to list result of mysql database in the web page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am very much new to java coding, by going through few online tutorials I was able to write a small project in spring mvc, I am trying to build a webapplication where I can store some applications repository like application name, host name (where it is running), application type, environment type (DEV, TEST, QA, PROD) into mysql table and fetch the same information to a webpage in form of tables. I was successful to achieve till this part but got stuck in the next step which is having a search field on the top of the table displayed in the webpage (table information fetched from mysql db ) where if we enter a keyword or any text it should search the db and fetch the result in the table (samepage).

This is what I have now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC98F.png)

jsp page which displays the table

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/style.css" />" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Client Management</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Client Data</h1>
<div >
<form:form method="POST" commandName="client">
<table class="myTable myTable-zebra myTable-horizontal">

  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Application Name</th>
    <th>Client Type</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th>Hostname</th>
    <th>Environment</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <c:forEach items="${clientList}" var="client">
        <tr>
            <td>${client.applicationname}</td>
            <td>${client.clienttype}</td>
            <td>${client.clientname}</td>
            <td>${client.hostname}</td>
            <td>${client.envtype}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
package com.webappdemo01.controller;            

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.webappdemo01.model.Client;
import com.webappdemo01.service.ClientService;

@Controller
public class ClientController {
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/AdminPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String adminpage() {
           return "AdminPage";
       } 

    @RequestMapping("/addclient")
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map){
        Client client = new Client();
        map.put("client", client);
        map.put("clientList", clientService.getAllClient());
        return "client";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/client.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Client client, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
        Client clientResult = new Client();
        switch(action.toLowerCase()){
        case "add":
            clientService.add(client);
            clientResult = client;
            break;
        case "edit":
            clientService.edit(client);
            clientResult = client;
            break;
        case "delete":
            clientService.delete(client.getClientname());
            clientResult = new Client();
            break;
        case "search":
            Client searchedClient = clientService.getClient(client.getClientname());
            clientResult = searchedClient!=null ? searchedClient : new Client();
            break;
        }
        map.put("client", clientResult);

        return "ClientAddSuccess";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/clientlist")
    public String clientPage(Map<String, Object> map){
        Client client = new Client();
        map.put("client", client);
        map.put("clientList", clientService.getAllClient());
        return "clientlist";
    }

}
```

Now I want to have search field on the top to fetch the result from db and display in the same table on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Without refreshing the page you can use javascript to make an ajax call to your controller for each word they are entering in your page and display the result